Given a sorted array of integers, how to find the longest sequence of numbers of the same value, and store said number in a pointer variable?
I want to write a C function that gets as arguments a sorted array of integers, its size and an integer pointer, and which accomplishes the following: 1. Finding and returning the length of the longest sequence of numbers of the same value in the sorted array, and 2. Storing the number from that sequence in the variable that the pointer given as argument is pointing at.
Here's my attempt that didn't yield the desired results, and I have no idea why.
Please suggest how I can fix my code so it would perform the desired task.
int MaxSequence(const int arr[], int size, int* number)
{
    int i = 0;
    int max = 1;
    int curr_max = 1;
    *number = arr[i];
    
    for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == arr[i+1]) {
            curr_max++;            
        }
        else if (curr_max > max) {
            max = curr_max;
            curr_max = 0;
            *number = arr[i];
        }               
    }

    return max;
}


Does this answer your question? What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?

What happens when both if conditions are false?

It doesn't give the desired results Perhaps you can show us an example of an array, the expected result, and the result you actually get?

int MaxSequence(const int arr[], int size, int* number)
{
    int i = 0;
    int max = 1;
    int curr_max = 1;
    *number = arr[i];
    
    for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == arr[i+1]) {
            curr_max++;            
        }
        else if (curr_max > max) {
            max = curr_max;
            curr_max = 0;
            *number = arr[i];
        } 
        else {
            curr_max = 0;
        }              
    }

    return max;
}

You are updating the curr_max when curr_max > max but we need to update it always when the number changes and update max only if curr_max is greater than current max value.
Added an else condition which will run when curr_max <= max and we do not need to update the max value and number pointer (Considering there will be only 1 number occurring max times)

In an extreme case, with MaxSequence(arr, 0, &number), this function returns 1, when 0 makes more sense.

else if (curr_max > max) { test is never executed if curr_max++; occurs in the last iteration.  Makes more sense to put  if (curr_max > max) { right after  curr_max++; with no curr_max = 0;.
